# No horizontal scrollbar with the PyDev Plugin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev

I am using Eclipse Luna (4.4.0) and have recently updated the PyDev for Eclipse plugin to 3.7.

It seems since the update, my horizontal scroll bar has disappeared:

[image]

I also notice the vertical bar has changed into the "Overview Ruler Minimap" (which I like). But I really need a horizontal bar.

Does anyone know how I can get it back?

Comment: Off-topic: Actually you shouldn't need horizontal scrollbar because PEP8 says that you shouldn't exceed 79 chars in line: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length. I know it is arguable but PEP8 also gives why it is important.

Comment: I use Django and their coding guidelines do say "One big exception to PEP 8 is our preference of longer line lengths. We’re well into the 21st Century, and we have high-resolution computer screens that can fit way more than 79 characters on a screen. Don’t limit lines of code to 79 characters if it means the code looks significantly uglier or is harder to read.". Anyway this is irrelevant because what if you have impaired eyesight and require a bigger font? Then it would be nice to scroll horizontally. I don't think it's offtopic.

Comment: By off-topic I mean I introduce off-topic. ;) As I said, 79 character length rule is very arguable but I found it useful because horizontal scrolling is counter productive for me. It's just my opinion, you can do whatever you want. ;)

Comment: Oh makes sense :) sorry I thought you were saying the question is off topic. Yep it's all about preference.

Comment: 79 characters doesn't mean that we don't need a scroll bar, depends on your screen size and font size. There are guys with vision problems out there, you know that right? Another OSS miss! The default should be "checked" (scrollbar visible).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Found the solution under Preferences > PyDev > Editor > Overview Ruler Minimap.

There is an option "Show horizontal scrollbar?"

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Mark.  This was especially annoying to me because the "minimap" ruler is completely broken if you collapse any blocks of code.